# $_ variable in script does not work as expected

Tags: linux, csh

I have c shell script that sources another:

```
source ./sc1.csh param
```

the script being sourced does the following:

```
set scriptName=($_)
if ( "$scriptName" == "" ) then
    set scriptName=$0
    echo "@**E: Please source this script, DO NOT RUN!"
    echo "ERROR"
    exit 1
else
    set scriptName=`basename $scriptName[2]`
endif
```

I expect $_ to contain "source ./sc1.csh param". However, it is actually empty. Manually running

```
source ./sc1.csh param
```

in the shell results in the correct, expected behavior. 
What's going on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From man csh

```
$_

Substitutes the command line of the last command executed. (+)
```

As the script has not completed execution yet, then $_ hasn't been set.

What happens if you call the script again?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you mean I should re-run the calling script?

If I can't use $_ in this context, how should the called script inspect the command used to call it?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so as user1717259 pointed out, $_ substitutes the command line of the last executed command, thus making it inappropriate for inspecting the command line inside the script being called. Instead, using $* (alias of $argv) works, as it contains all of the command line except for "source" itself.